# Node.js convert Object to string and string to Object?

Tags: node.js, string, object

I have an instance of a Class named P

```
const stringifyObject = require('stringify-object');

JSON.parse(stringifyObject(P));
```

Which returns the following error:

```
_readableState: {
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 3
 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Read the docs on [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). It will throw an exception if you pass an invalid JSON string into it.

Comment: OK, but how do I convert an Object into a string and back then?

Comment: pass a valid JSON string into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object to string : `JSON.stringify`

```
var a = {a:"2da",b:"xfgsfg"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

String to Object: `JSON.parse`

```
var s = '{"a":"2da","b":"xfgsfg"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

The NPM package `stringify-object` doesn't produce a JSON compliant string. You can use the built-in [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get a string, and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn it back into an object.

```
const obj = {a: 1};
const str = JSON.stringify(obj); // '{"a":1}'
const deserialisedObj = JSON.parse(str); // {a: 1}
obj.a === deserialisedObj.a; // true
```